# Filtering the items in SearchResultCollection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, search, sitecore, sitecore6

I built a function where I am passing the string of countries that I want to search and the number of articles that I want to get from the search result.

But when the search is coming back from the Sitecore Content Items, I dont want to show the items which has an asterisk **(*)** in the starting of their **Title** field. Here is the function name:

```
 protected IEnumerable<Item> ShowHomePageNews(int numOfArticles, string stringofCountries)
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        Sitecore.Search.Index indx = SearchManager.GetIndex("my_index_name");
        using (IndexSearchContext searchContext = indx.CreateSearchContext())
        {
            CombinedQuery query = new CombinedQuery();
            QueryBase catQuery = new FieldQuery("countries", stringofCountries); //FieldName, FieldValue.
            SearchHits results = searchContext.Search(catQuery); //Searching the content items by fields.
            SearchResultCollection result = results.FetchResults(0, numOfArticles);
            foreach (SearchResult i in result)
            {
                Lucene.Net.Documents.Field url = i.Document.GetField("_url");
                Sitecore.Data.ItemUri itemUri = new Sitecore.Data.ItemUri(url.StringValue());
                Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(itemUri.ToDataUri());
                items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
```

And I am calling this function on my PageLoad:

rptHomePageNews.DataSource = ShowHomePageNews(4, "USA");

And this is my markup:

```
<asp:Panel ID="HomePageNews" runat="server">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptHomePageNews" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <li>
        <%--<sc:FieldRenderer ID="FieldRenderer1" FieldName="Date" runat="server" Item="<%# Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item %>" />--%>
        <a href="<%# Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item) %>">
           <sc:FieldRenderer ID="FieldRenderer2" FieldName="Title" runat="server" Item="<%# Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item %>" />
        </a>
    </li>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What changes should I make in my ShowHomePageNews function?

Comment: Are you interested in doing the filtering in the search, or are you willing to use post-search LINQ query filtering?

Comment: Yes! I am willing to do that.

Comment: My 'result' variable is 0 here. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach here is to do post-filtering using a LINQ query, something like this:

```
string myTitleField = "My Title Field";
List<Item> results = items.Where(x => x.Fields[myTitleField].Value.Contains("*") == false).ToList();
```

This is not efficient, as you will need to load all of the Items before you start filtering.  If efficiency is not a concern, then this at least provides a simple way to filter.

My suggestion, however, would be to add a field to your index and flag the record with a value you can filter on (such as "TitleContainsAsterisk").  You could then alter your query to filter out results that have 'true' or a '1' in that field.

**EDIT** (for Advanced Database Crawler)
Configuration and code example for adding a dynamic field. **Note** I have not compiled or run this, I'm pseudo-coding off of existing code I have:

```
<dynamicFields hint="raw:AddDynamicFields">
    <dynamicField type="MyNameSpace.TitleContainsAsterisk,MyBinary" 
        name="TitleContainsAsterisk" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
</dynamicFields>

/// <summary>
/// Field Configuration (for the indexer) to index the if there is an asterisk in the title
/// </summary>
public class TitleContainsAsterisk: BaseDynamicField {
    public override string ResolveValue(Item item) {
        string myTitleField = "My Title Field";
        bool containsAsterisk = item.Fields[myTitleField].Value.Contains("*");
        return containsAsterisk ? "1" : "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, have you implemented indexing in Sitecore 6.5?

Comment: I haven't personally written the code or configurations for 6.5 indexing, but have done so in 6.4.  My team has been working with 6.5 indexing for some time now, however.

Comment: I added some examples for how to add the field and put a value in for 6.5 Advanced Database Crawler from Alex Shyba.  Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to use Linq, you could replace the foreach loop with something like this:

```
var db = Sitecore.Context.Database;

items = result
         .Where(r => !r.Title.StartsWith("*"))
         .Select(r => db.GetItem(new Sitecore.Data.ItemUri(r.Url).ToDataUri()))
         .ToList();
```

Comment: The variable `result` refers to the same variable in your example: `SearchResultCollection result`